# How can I set the returned value of this Stub object?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, rhino-mocks, arrange-act-assert

```
public interface IMyINterface
{
    int GetMeSomeInteger();
    Toy GetMeAToy(string toyName);
}


[TestMethod]
public void PlayWithANumber_RecievesInteger_DoRightJob()
{

    IMyINterface stub = MockRepository.GenerateStub<IMyINterface>();

    // HOW CAN I? :
    // Instruct GetMeSomeIngeter() method in stub to return 5

    // HOW CAN I? :
    // Instruct GetMeAToy(string toyName) method in stub to return
      //new Toy() {ToyName = "Gizmo", Code = "0989"}

      var five = stub.GetMeSomeInteger();
      var gizmo = GetMeAToy("Gizmo");
      Assert.IsTrue(DoSomething(five, gizmo) == 100 );    
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Scenario 1:**

```
var myInterface = MockRepository.GenerateStub<IMyINterface>();
myInterface.Stub(x => x.GetMeSomeIngeter()).Return(5);
```

**Scenario 2:**

```
var myInterface = MockRepository.GenerateStub<IMyINterface>();
myInterface.Stub(x => x.GetMeAToy("Gizmo")).Return(new Toy() {ToyName = "Gizmo", Code = "0989"});
```

Comment: But I don't need a mock; I need a stub. Besides, do you think we can approach this without using Record; what I mean is by Arrange-Assert-Act approach?

Comment: I described only Arrange step.. You also need to invoke your members (this will be Act) and then check returned values (will be Assert).

Comment: I've left only latest samples.